# ggplot2 bar plot color changing

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Altuz.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIlNA.jpg)I wanted to make a bar graph with ggplot. I specify the order and colors for "fill" but one bar's order and color do not change. Here are my codes:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Groups, y = Ratio, fill = Domains), position = "dodge") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(C1 = "pink", V1 = "blue", V2 = "maroon", C2 = "orange", 
                                V3 = "violet", C3 = "green", V4 = "brown", C4 = "sky blue", 
                                V5 = "red", C5 = "yellow", GP41 = "tan"), aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels = c("C1", "V1", "V2", "C2", "V3", "C3", "V4", "C4", "V5", "C5", "GP41"))
```

Although C5's color in the label is marked by yellow but it does not get changed in the graph and it comes after GP41. Only this bar has an issue.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help us to help you would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Comment: This said, one reason for this kind of issue might be that there is no category "C5" in you data or some kind of typo, e.g. the category contains a leading space. To check have a look at `data$Domains` or `unique(data$Domains)`.

Comment: It seems like C5 has no data to show in the bar graph. It is hard to know, though, if you don't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?ssslallow). For R it is very easy with [reprex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/vignettes/reprex-dos-and-donts.html)

Answer (score 1):

While the order of the named `vector` supplied to `values` within `scale_fill_manual()` determines the order in the legend, it doesn't dictate the order of the bars. You show code to set the order of the levels for `data$Domains` but it looks like you're running it **after** the plotting. Try doing it before and see if that helps.

Here's an example of what I mean about the order of the legend vs the order of the bars in the plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
            y = runif(1:9),
            grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 3))

colours <- setNames(c("cadetblue", "hotpink", "black"), 
                    c("C", "B", "A"))

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine and C5 contains value then the issue is where you define the levels of your domains variable (eg. before or after the ggplot()).

You can also use @stefan's code line:

```
data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels=unique(data$Domains))
```

Sample code:

```
data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels = c("C1", "V1", "V2", "C2", "V3", "C3", "V4", "C4", "V5", "C5", "GP41"))  # before the ggplot
#data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels=unique(data$Domains))


 library (ggplot2)



data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels = c("C1", "V1", "V2", "C2", "V3", "C3", "V4", "C4", "V5", "C5", "GP41"))  # before the ggplot
#data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels=unique(data$Domains))

data$Groups <-factor(data$Groups, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

library (ggplot2)


ggplot(data) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Groups, y = Ratio, fill = Domains), position = "dodge") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(C1 = "pink", V1 = "blue", V2 = "maroon", C2 = "orange", 
                                V3 = "violet", C3 = "green", V4 = "brown", C4 = "sky blue", 
                                V5 = "red", C5 = "yellow", GP41 = "tan"), aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample code:

```
data$Groups <-factor(data$Groups, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))


library (ggplot2)

 ggplot(data) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Groups, y = Ratio, fill = Domains), position = "dodge") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(C1 = "pink", V1 = "blue", V2 = "maroon", C2 = "orange", 
                                V3 = "violet", C3 = "green", V4 = "brown", C4 = "sky blue", 
                                V5 = "red", C5 = "yellow", GP41 = "tan"), aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))+
  theme_minimal())

data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels = c("C1", "V1", "V2", "C2", "V3", "C3", "V4", "C4", "V5", "C5", "GP41")) 

#after the ggplot. If you look at the plot, you'll notice that the order is alphabetical: C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,GP41, V1,V2,V3,V4 and V5
    #data$Domains <- factor(data$Domains, levels=unique(data$Domains))
```

Plot: #As you can see, the bars are arranged in alphabetical order.

[image]

Sample data:

```
        data<-structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
NA), Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Domains = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA), .Label = c("C1", "V1", 
    "V2", "C2", "V3", "C3", "V4", "C4", "V5", "C5", "GP41"), class = "factor"), 
    Ratio = c(0.231, 0.2, 0.359, 0.357, 0.371, 0.462, 0.424, 
    0.35, 0.3, 0.4, 0.358, 0.5, 0.16, 0.41, 0.531, 0.514, 0.692, 
    0.515, 0.45, 0.2, 0.575, 0.401, 0.362, 0.36, 0.36, 0.571, 
    0.371, 0.571, 0.484, 0.425, 0.1, 0.375, 0.408, 0.4, 0.16, 
    0.256, 0.54, 0.514, 0.538, 0.666, 0.175, 0.4, 0.4, 0.42, 
    NA), ...5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(...1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Groups = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Domains = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Ratio = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ...5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I attached the sample of the data that I used. C5 has value in it but specifically for C5, I can't change either the color or the order.

Comment: can you dput(data)

Comment: @Elmira could englarge the image or post dput(data)

Comment: I reupload the picture of the data set. When I make the data frame by codes that you posted, it works fine. But when I used the CSV file, it had the same issue. I am curious to know what the problem is with my datasets.

Comment: @Elmira updated the post with your code and it is working fine